# Android Studio app not communicating with 000webhost to populate database

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I have built my app and uploaded necessary php files to 000webhost with guidance from videos that are about 4 years old as I cannot find anything more recent.  The app does not communicate with the server to populate the database that I created.  I am new to this and finally figured out that if I look at the site I am trying to access with a RegisterReqest.java it tells me the issues.  I do not know how to rectify these issues.  Can anyone help?  The issues are posted in first below.

**https://suppliesme.000webhostapp.com/register.php:**

```
Notice: Undefined index: messengername in /storage/ssd2/807/13826807/public_html/register.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: zip_code in /storage/ssd2/807/13826807/public_html/register.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: email in /storage/ssd2/807/13826807/public_html/register.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: password in /storage/ssd2/807/13826807/public_html/register.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: purpose in /storage/ssd2/807/13826807/public_html/register.php on line 8

Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /storage/ssd2/807/13826807/public_html/register.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /storage/ssd2/807/13826807/public_html/register.php on line 12
{"success":true}
```

**RegisterRequest.java code**

```
package com.example.android.myapplication;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "https://suppliesme.000webhostapp.com/register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public RegisterRequest(String messengername, String zip_code, String email, String password, String purpose, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("messengername", messengername);
        params.put("zip_code", zip_code);
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("password", password);
        params.put("purpose", purpose);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

**Register.php:**

```
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id13826807_suppliesmeadmin", "password", "id13826807_suppliesme");
    
    $messengernamename = $_POST["messengername"];
    $zip_code = $_POST["zip_code"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $purpose = $_POST["purpose"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (messengername, email, zip_code, password, purpose) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sssss", $messengername, $zip_code, $email, $password, $purpose);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    
    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  
    
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.